# Trying to get response when element is clicked

Tags: jquery

I've got this simple code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".map-marker").click(function(){  
        console.log("clicked");
        var latitude = $(this).data("data-latitude");
    });    
});
```

And I have an HTML element:

```
<img class="map-marker" data-latitude="50.350520295349" data-longitude="50.350520295349" src="assets/img/markers/0.png">
```

But for some reason this simple code isn't working. If I put the console.log outside of the click function, as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    console.log("clicked");
    $(".map-marker").click(function(){
        var latitude = $(this).data("data-latitude");
    });    
});
```

I get the desired response in the console. So, I know that a) jQuery has loaded, b) the `$(document).ready` function is firing. So what reason might cause my original code not to fire when the element is clicked?

Comment: It works here in my JSFiddle... 
It must be something else in your code, could you post more code?
http://jsfiddle.net/4uTwA/1/

Comment: @JOSEFtw I've just found that this is something to do with that I'm using AngularJS. The <img> is inside an ng-repeat - when I put it outside it works. I guess I'll have to find an 'angular' way of doing it.

Comment: I think you should look at the other answers and use .on('click'... instead :)

Answer (score 2):

you want:

```
var latitude = $(this).attr("data-latitude");
```

or you may be thinking of:

```
 var latitude = $(this).data("latitude");
```

if the click isn't firinig ,  then use this instead

```
    $(document).on("click", ".map-marker", function(){


    });
```

the reason for `.on()` is because I am guessing that the element you are talking about was created dynamically ( after document.ready() )  when the first code was executed.  If the element is not there at the time of document.ready() then you have to use `.on()`

that is my best guess - because as the comments say , the code in OP is valid working code,  except of course for the `.data("data-latitude")` , but that was addressed as well

Comment: Thanks, but whatever that line does, the console.log should still fire - my problem is that the click function doesn't seem to be firing.

Comment: You need the second method of binding the handler if the map-markers are added dynamically to the DOM.

Comment: explained that as well

Comment: Ah that's it. The element is indeed created dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

It should be either:

```
$(this).data('latitude')
```

or:

```
$(this).attr('data-latitude')
```

When you use the `data()` method, it automatically adds the `data-` prefix to the name.

Note that you should either use `.attr()` or `.data()` consistently, not mix them with the same attribute, because `.data()` caches the attribute value the first time it accesses it.

Comment: I feel smart - same answer , but faster then someone with 116k rep

Answer (score -1):

`$(this).attr("data-latitude");` is what you are looking for. Attr stands for attribute and it is how you get the value of attributes that you set in HTML.

Are you sure that you are including your JS file or if your function is in scope?

Comment: He could (should?) also use $(this).data("latitude") instead

Comment: he is sure - as the console.log() is executing